# Comparing dates in list with date ranges in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I'm having difficulty figuring out a way to count the occurrences of holidays between datetime ranges in a dataframe. The holidays are in a list while the datetime ranges are in the dataframe as shown below: (note that this is a subset of a very large data set)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2018-12-19 18:47','2019-01-01 06:11','2019-01-12 10:05','2019-02-17 14:22','2019-03-08 16:17','2019-03-25 17:35','2019-02-14 17:35'],
              'End Date': ['2018-12-28 18:47','2019-01-05 06:11','2019-01-16 10:05','2019-02-19 14:22','2019-03-12 16:17','2019-03-26 17:35','2019-05-27 17:35']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'])

Holidays = [date(2018,12,24),date(2018,12,25),date(2019,1,1),date(2019,1,21),date(2019,2,18),date(2019,3,8),date(2019,5,27)]
```

I've been able to find a way that determine whether or not a Holiday is within the datetime ranges, but not get an actual count.

Is there a way to alter the code below to gather the count rather than boolean values?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
df['Holidays'] = [any([(z>=x)&(z<=y) for z in Holidays]) for x , y in zip(df['Date'].dt.date,df['End Date'].dt.date)]
```

The result I'm looking for is as follows:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2018-12-19 18:47','2019-01-01 06:11','2019-01-12 10:05','2019-02-17 14:22','2019-03-08 16:17','2019-03-25 17:35','2019-02-14 17:35'],
                   'End Date': ['2018-12-28 18:47','2019-01-05 06:11','2019-01-16 10:05','2019-02-19 14:22','2019-03-12 16:17','2019-03-26 17:35','2019-05-27 17:35'],
                   'Holidays': [2,1,0,1,1,0,3]})
```

Comment: your desired output is incorrect because the `Holidays` list has no hours but you are disregarding that and simply checking by day

Answer (score 1):

We can make a function that checks this condition and then `apply` it row-wise.

```
def fn(series):
    return sum([series.iloc[0] <= h <= series.iloc[1] for h in Holidays])

df.assign(Holidays=df.apply(fn, axis=1))

                 Date            End Date  Holidays
0 2018-12-19 18:47:00 2018-12-28 18:47:00         2
1 2019-01-01 06:11:00 2019-01-05 06:11:00         0
2 2019-01-12 10:05:00 2019-01-16 10:05:00         0
3 2019-02-17 14:22:00 2019-02-19 14:22:00         1
4 2019-03-08 16:17:00 2019-03-12 16:17:00         0
5 2019-03-25 17:35:00 2019-03-26 17:35:00         0
6 2019-02-14 17:35:00 2019-05-27 17:35:00         3
```

Your desired output is incorrect because the `Holidays` list has no hours for any of the date timestamps. To get the output that you posted we will have to round down to the day.

```
def fn(series):
    return sum([series.iloc[0].floor('d') <= h <= series.iloc[1].floor('d') for h in Holidays])

df.assign(Holidays=df.apply(fn, axis=1))

               Date          End Date  Holidays
0  2018-12-19 18:47  2018-12-28 18:47         2
1  2019-01-01 06:11  2019-01-05 06:11         1
2  2019-01-12 10:05  2019-01-16 10:05         0
3  2019-02-17 14:22  2019-02-19 14:22         1
4  2019-03-08 16:17  2019-03-12 16:17         1
5  2019-03-25 17:35  2019-03-26 17:35         0
6  2019-02-14 17:35  2019-05-27 17:35         3
```